# A Circular view of 24hr, a Day tasks?

Tags: project-management, time-management, task-management, planning

Is there any software, webapp, or any task manager, project manager, 
which can give a Circular view of 24 hr, and Tasks in it.. if not how can I create a Pie Chart like that..
Im looking to create a Circle of 24hr with tasks in each arc, and a Circke of week, with days, and unique task related to that day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Microsoft Excel](https://products.office.com/en/excel), probably also [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/calc/).

Just add your tasks and the time you spent on them. For the "rest of the day", use the formula `=1-SUM(B1:B4)` (or whatever range your tasks are).

[image: Screenshot]